# In Anchor, how do I init a callee's account that's used to create CpiContext in caller's program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, pda, cpi

I'm trying to make CPI to the callee program to initialize a config account when I do initialization in caller's program. One of the accounts used in callee's initialization used #[account(init)], but then when I create the CPI context, how am I supposed to do the init?

Caller's (A) program:

```
pub mod A {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_A(ctx: Context<CreateA>) -> Result<()> {
        let A = &mut ctx.accounts.A;
        A.data = 0;
        A.B = ctx.accounts.B_program.key();
        B::cpi::create_B(ctx.accounts.create_B_ctx())
    }
}

pub struct CreateA<'info> {
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = user, 
        space = 32 + 8 + 4 + 1, 
        seeds = [user.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub a: Account<'info, A>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,

    // how do I init B account here?
    #[account(mut)]
    pub b: Account<'info, B>,
    pub B_program: Program<'info, B_program>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

impl<'info> CreateA<'info> {
    pub fn create_B_ctx(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, CreateB<'info>> {
        let B_program_id = self.B_program.to_account_info();
        let B_accounts = CreateB {
            b: self.b.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.user.to_account_info(),
            system_program: self.system_program.to_account_info(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(B_program_id, B_accounts)
    }
}
```

Callee's (B) program:

```
#[program]
pub mod B {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_b(ctx: Context<CreateB>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateB<'info> {
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = authority, 
        space = B::LEN, 
        seeds = [
            authority.key().as_ref(), 
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub b: Account<'info, B>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: The accounts are created for you automatically by Anchor, using the passed-in `system_program`. You shouldn't need to do anything. Are you getting an error?

Comment: You should initialize the callee and caller program separately and when doing cpi call to callee, just pass the caller account.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to pass b as an Account<'info, B> makes checks fail. The reason is that the createA validator expects b to have been created since it's not being marked with init. The paradox is that the account obviously hasn't been created yet which is why you want the CPI call to do it.

To get around this you have to pass b as an AccountInfo<'info> in CreateA. This ensures that the Caller program doesn't run any checks and should pass it to the Callee with no problems.

```
pub struct CreateA<'info> {
#[account(
    init, 
    payer = user, 
    space = 32 + 8 + 4 + 1, 
    seeds = [user.key().as_ref()], 
    bump
)]
pub a: Account<'info, A>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user: Signer<'info>,

// how do I init B account here?
/// CHECK: All verification is done by the CPI call to B
#[account(mut, signer)]
pub b: AccountInfo<'info>,
pub B_program: Program<'info, B_program>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
```

}

This should work. The signer attribute is needed here because a program needs to sign its own creation and the caller has to pass that privilege to the callee. The caveat to doing things this way though is that the account being initialized cannot be a PDA.

Here's an example of how I did this myself:

**The caller:**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCounterWhitelist<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["counter".as_bytes().as_ref(), authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority,
    )]
    counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    /// CHECK: Verification done by CPI to whitelist program
    whitelist_config: AccountInfo<'info>,
    whitelist_program: Program<'info, Whitelist>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

**The callee:**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateWhitelist<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        space = WhitelistConfig::LEN,
    )]
    whitelist_config: Account<'info, WhitelistConfig>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Here, *whitelist_config* is the account being initialized by CPI.

Comment: a functional code sample would be great!

Comment: @trent.sol Just did that!

Comment: But it requires another signer, how can we sign with that white list config?

Comment: Here I added `whitelistConfig` to the signers array of the `createCounterWhitelist` instruction, which passed the privilege to `createWhitelist`